# Category Template - Show Last Entry as Featured

Tags: categories, templates

I am working on my category template.  Here is how I want the page to display:

1. Category Name - `this is done`
2. The latest post for each category be on top `(then styled which I can do)`.
3. The Category description - `this is done`
4. List all the rest of the posts for the category under it - `I can list all the posts, but I want to skip the latest`

Any help in pointing me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WP_Query's built in `current_post` counter in your loop:

```
while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();
    if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ):
        // this is the first post in the loop
    else:
        // this is > first post
    endif;
endwhile;
```

EDIT w/html:

```
<?php
while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();
    if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ):
        ?>
        featured post

        category description

        <ul>
        <?php
    else:
        ?>
        <li>post</li>
        <?php
    endif;
endwhile;
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: How does that work with putting code in between?  I want to put the description after the first post and an `ul` list around the n+1 posts.

Comment: @Martin see edit above

Answer (score 0):

Create a $counter variable (that equals 0 at the beginning) outside of the posts loop. Increment the variable by 1 in the loop. Again, inside the loop check if the counter is 0, if yes - do nothing, if it's bigger than 0 - show the post. :)

Comment: Show how do I get the latest post for the category?  Run the loop twice?